# \usepackage{sectsty} and LaTeX Error: Command \sectionrule already defined

Tags: fonts, moderncv, sectsty

I am new to LATEX. I was using latex to build my resume but encountered errors when using \usepackage{sectsty} with "moderncv" document class:\

LaTeX Error: Command \sectionrule already defined. 
LaTeX Error: Command \sectionfont already defined. 
LaTeX Error: Command \subsectionfont already defined.
Package sectsty Error: The sectsty package doesn't work with\

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}       
\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                
\nopagenumbers{}                                 

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
    \geometry{letterpaper, top = 20mm, bottom = 20mm}
\usepackage{multicol}


\usepackage{import}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{22}{40}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\fontsize{10}{20}\mdseries\upshape}
```

Any idea how to fix this? I was trying to shrink the font size of subsection and name.

Comment: Why do you need to load `sectsty`? The `\namefont` and `\subsectionfont` macros are already defined in the `moderncv` class.

Comment: Off-topic: Since the `fontspec` package is loaded, you shouldn't load the `inputenc` package.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions! Both are helpful! I am new to LATEX and moderncv and don't know much about this documentclass or packages like fontspec. Just trying to modify some prebuilt templates.

Answer (score 1):

Class `moderncv` is simply not compatible with package `sectsty`. You can see this in the resulting error message in the `.log` file:

```
! Package sectsty Error: The sectsty package doesn't work with
(sectsty)                this document class.

See the sectsty package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.296     scrartcl, scrbook, and scrreprt.}
                                           
The sectsty package only works with the following classes: 
the standard LaTeX document classes
article, report, and book; and
the KOMA-Script classes
scrartcl, scrbook, and scrreprt.
```

After commenting the call of `sectsty` and correcting some other errors (see marking `<======` in the following MWE) and adding the missing parts to have a compilable code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % <===================== use inputenc or fontspec
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{sectsty} % <================== not compatible with moderncv

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
    \geometry{letterpaper, top = 20mm, bottom = 20mm}
\usepackage{multicol}


%\usepackage{import} % <============================================ ???
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{22}{40}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\fontsize{10}{20}\mdseries\upshape}

% <======================================================== missing part
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

you can compile without errors and get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]